# rollup --config gives : [!] SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs

I'm trying to learn how to use rollup to package some javascript, following some tutorial on the net.
I stuck at the very beginning trying to use a config file.
With command line everything seems OK, but with a config file it ends with an `Unexpected token 'export'` syntax error.

My config is Windows 11 with:

```
c:\dev\rollup-test>node --version
v16.14.2
c:\dev\rollup-test>rollup --version
rollup v2.70.1
```

Config file :

```
c:\dev\rollup-test>type rollup.config.js
export default {
    input: './src/main.js',
    output: {
      file: './build/bundle.js',
      format: 'es'
    }
  };
```

The javascript file `src\main.js`:

```
c:\dev\rollup-test>type src\main.js
console.log('hi there!');
```

In CLI mode, everything seems OK:

```
c:\dev\rollup-test>rollup ./src/main.js --file ./build/bundle.js --format es

./src/main.js → ./build/bundle.js...
created ./build/bundle.js in 29ms
```

Trying to use the config file above:

```
c:\dev\rollup-test>rollup --config
[!] SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
c:\dev.local\rollup-test\rollup.config.js:1
export default {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\Users\joelh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\loadConfigFile.js:617:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at loadConfigFromBundledFile (C:\Users\joelh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\loadConfigFile.js:622:42)

c:\dev\rollup-test>
```

There's probably something so obvious, but alas I can't see it.
Can anyone help me to go further ?

Comment: `export` is ES6 Module syntax. Have you added the property `"type":"module"` to your `package.json`?

Comment: Should have mentioned, if you are not using ES modules, you can use `module.exports` instead: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#using-untranspiled-config-files

Comment: Rollup expects the config file to be an ES module by default, so it should work (and it does for me, with same rollup version and node v17.3.0)

Comment: @Tim I have no package.json. Do I have to create one? I didn't see that mentionned in rollup tutorial.

Comment: @Vincent I just installed node v17.8.0, but have no luck: the same error occurs :(

Comment: @Tim I replaced `export default` with `module.exports` in the config file and I still don't know why but at least now it works! :) TY @all for spending of your time on my case.

Comment: @JoëlHecht, You don't necessarily need a package.json if you don't intend to deploy your package.  But remember Node.js uses the CommonJS module loader by default.  So unless you specifically tell Node.js to use the ES modules, you can't use ES Module syntax such as `export`.  [See here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#enabling)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

The solution was to add a line to package.json
"type": "module",

```
package.json
```

```js
{
  "name": "Webpack, rollup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Webpack",
    "rollup"
  ],
  "author": "Igor Kiselov",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "rollup": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have it in my pkg.json file, not working!

Comment: Greate Solution