# node module package using import/export syntax and rollup fails to build it

Tags: rollup, rollupjs

I'm trying to use a package that is using import/export syntax (es module), I have `"type": "module",` in my package.json and when I try to build my project using rollup, I get:

```js
[!] SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
export { I18n } from "./I18n"; // <- the index file of package in my node_module folder
^^^^^^
  ... a bunch of call stack
```

I already have `nodeResolve()` in my config file, also my config file is like `rollup.config.js` format (.mjs did not anything as well), my node version is v18.16.0 but I don't know what is wrong with my config or build process.

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698183/rollup-config-gives-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export) but no luck at all

Do you have any idea why?